# Django updating model BooleanField not working

Tags: python, django, django-models

model

```
public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

view

```
@login_required
def topic_visibility(request, topic_id, visibility):
    """Change topic visibility, then redirect to topics page"""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)

    check_instance_ownership(request, topic)

    if visibility == 0:
        topic.public = False
    elif visibility == 1:
        topic.public = True

    return redirect('learning_logs:topic', topic_id = topic_id)
```

url pattern

```
    path('topic_visibility/<int:topic_id>/<int:visibility>', views.topic_visibility, name="topic_visibility"),
```

A button dropdown allows the user to select whether they want a certain forum topic to be public (True) or private (False).

When the user visits the url that calls `topic_visibility` in the view, nothing is changed. I suspect it may have something to do with the topic model not being saved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not *save* the model object, so the change does not persists:

```
@login_required
def topic_visibility(request, topic_id, visibility):
    """Change topic visibility, then redirect to topics page"""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    check_instance_ownership(request, topic)
    if visibility == 0:
        topic.public = False
    elif visibility == 1:
        topic.public = True
    topic.save()
    return redirect('learning_logs:topic', topic_id=topic_id)
```

> **Note**: A GET request is *not* supposed to have *side-effects*, hence updating
>   objects when a user makes a GET request, is not compliant with the HTTP
>   standard. Therefore it might be better to update a `Topic` with a POST request.

Comment: could you explain how I may do so? I've realized that much of my backend does similar changes

Comment: @pyknight202: you should make a POST request, for example with a `<form>` in HTML, and you can restrict the view with [`@allowed_http_methods`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/decorators/#allowed-http-methods) decorator.

Answer (score 1):

You must use update():

```
 Topic.objects.filter(id__exact=topic_id).update(public=True)
```